# How to terminate a computation that runs in the `IO` monad?

Tags: haskell, exception, io, monads, short-circuiting

There is a library that provides a data type `F` and a function of type

```
ffoldlIO :: (b -> a -> IO b) -> b -> F a -> IO b
```

The function is similar to

```
foldlIO :: (b -> a -> IO b) -> b -> [a] -> IO b
foldlIO f a = \xs -> foldr (\x r (!a') -> f a' x >>= r) return xs a
```

I wonder whether `foldlIO` (and thus `ffoldlIO`) can run in a short-circuit fashion.

Consider this example:

```
example1 :: IO Int
example1 = foldlIO (\a x -> if a < 4 then return (a + x) else return a) 0 [1..5]
```

Here `foldlIO` traverses the entire list, but what if we throw an exception to stop the computation and then catch it? Something like this:

```
data Terminate = Terminate
  deriving (Show)

instance Exception Terminate

example2 :: IO Int
example2 = do
  ra <- newIORef 0
  let step a x
        | a' < 4    = return a'
        | otherwise = writeIORef ra a' >> throwIO Terminate
        where a' = a + x
  foldlIO step 0 [1..] `catch` \(_ :: Terminate) -> readIORef ra
```

Is this reliable? Is there a better way to terminate a computation that runs in the `IO` monad (and no other monad) or am I not supposed to do this at all?

Answer (score 3):

For example, you can use `ContT` monad transformer like this:

```
example3 :: IO Int
example3 = flip runContT return . callCC $ \exit -> do
    let step a x
            | a' < 4    = return a'
            | otherwise = exit a'
            where a' = a + x
    foldM step 0 [1..]
```

Also, you can define you own version of `foldM` with posibility of termination.

```
termFoldM :: (Monad m, Foldable t) =>
    ((b -> ContT b m c) -> b -> a -> ContT b m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
termFoldM f a t = flip runContT return . callCC $ \exit -> foldM (f exit) a xs

example4 :: IO Int
example4 = termFoldM step 0 [1..]
  where
    step exit a x
        | a' < 4    = return a'
        | otherwise = exit a'
        where a' = a + x
```

But this way (with `ContT`) has one problem. You can't easy do some `IO` actions. For example, this code will not be compiled, because `step` function must return value of type `ContT Int IO Int` not `IO Int`.

```
let step a x
        | a' < 4    = putStrLn ("'a = " ++ show a') >> return a'
        | otherwise = exit a'
        where a' = a + x
```

Fortunately, you can solve this by the `lift` function, like this:

```
let step a x
        | a' < 4    = lift (putStrLn ("'a = " ++ show a')) >> return a'
        | otherwise = exit a'
        where a' = a + x
```

Comment: This is more or less what I wrote as well. `ContT` is (in)famous for being hard to beginners, so some more comment would help as well. I'd also suggest to add `lift (putStrLn "foo") >> ...` somewhere so to show how to to IO within `ContT _ IO _`.

Comment: This computation runs in `ContT Int IO Int` instead of plain `IO` as I requested. I'll edit the question to make it less confusing, sorry.

Comment: "you can define you own version of `foldM`" — I can't: the library provides only `ffoldlIO` and it's far too complicated to implement my own `foldM`. Lists in the question are just for an example of what I want to achieve.

Comment: @user3237465 I think you solution is the best if you don't want to use monad transformers. But why don't you want?

Comment: @freestyle, it's not that I don't want — I just can't. The library I'm using provides a data type `f` and the only folding function over it runs in the `IO` monad. And that `f` is too complicated, so I can't implement something that runs in any `MonadIO` instead of plain `IO`. I already implemented some combinators to add `StateT` and `ExceptT` layers on top of `IO` (by manually wrapping and unwrapping everything), but now I need early termination and the `Terminate` solution looks like a dirty hack.

Comment: @user3237465 Sorry, I didn't pay attention to it.

Answer (score 1):

My first answer was not correct. So, I'll try to improve.

---

I think that the use of exceptions to terminate in IO monad is not a hack but it does not look clean. I propose to define the instance `MonadCont IO` like this:

```
data Terminate = forall a . Terminate a deriving (Typeable)
instance Show Terminate where show = const "Terminate"
instance Exception Terminate

instance MonadCont IO where
    callCC f = f exit `catch` (\(Terminate x) -> return . unsafeCoerce $ x)
      where exit = throwIO . Terminate
```

Then you can rewrite your example more cleaner.

```
example :: IO Int
example = callCC $ \exit -> do
    let step a x
            | a' < 4    = return a'
            | otherwise = exit a'
            where a' = a + x
    foldlIO step 0 [1..]
```

---

Variant with `IOREf`.

```
data Terminate = Terminate deriving (Show, Typeable)
instance Exception Terminate

instance MonadCont IO where
    callCC f = do
        ref <- newIORef undefined
        let exit a = writeIORef ref a >> throwIO Terminate
        f exit `catch` (\Terminate -> readIORef ref)
```

Comment: That's a nice trick, thanks. Though, I don't want to introduce orphan instances and I already have a [machinery](https://github.com/effectfully/prefolds) that allows to write short-circuiting folds, so I just need to interpret such folds in the `IO` monad, and I'm still not sure about the `Terminate` approach. Do you maybe have a reference that confirms this approach is OK? A paper that mentions it, or a commonly used library or something like this.

Comment: @user3237465 No, I don't. But I known one potential problem with this approach - someone can catch all exceptions and this can broken your program. Fortunately, this is unlikely. So, it is bad idea to use this approach everywhere, but in some cases it can be possible.

Comment: That's a good observation. Then I'll just store accumulators in an `IORef` and a final value always will be in the `IORef` no matter whether an exception was thrown and no matter whether it was caught by someone.